# Dealing with highly skewed residuals in GLMM

Tags: r, residuals, glmm, skewness, ecology

I am trying to see if there is a relation between the proportion of target vs non target species in some communities and their phylogenetic structure. I cannot show you the real data but it looks something similar to this (although I have over 18000 data points and 'hab' has 12 levels):

```
df <- structure(list(hab = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,12L, 12L, 9L),   
   .Label = c("Eur_nitro_herb", "Forest_deciduous","Forest_everg_Eur",  
   "Forest_med", "Grass_alp", "Grass_mont_subalp","Margin_mantle", "Med_nitro_herb", "Rocks",     "Shrub_med", "Shrub_mont_subalp","Wet_humid"), class = "factor"), 
   ses_mpd = c(0.05408747785078,-0.578266990137644, -1.48812316684822, -0.345401572814568,  0.124151290090708,-1.51817069020564, 0.0530607986221243, 0.00261416940904258, 0.665908557766837,-0.701477005797007), 
   target = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),non_target = c(32, 27, 20, 30, 34, 26, 30, 9, 12, 6)), row.names = c(1L,2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 18793L, 18794L, 18795L), class = "data.frame") 

df
```

ses.mpd as calculated by the picante package is a standarized size effect so it can take positive and negative values as well as zero.
I want to see the relationship between proportion of target and non target with ses_mpd controlling for possible differences between habitats. I have used a Generalized Linear Mixed Model to do so but when I check the residuals they look fairly skewed:

```
library(lme4)
mod<-glmer(cbind(target,non_target)~ses_mpd+(1|hab), family = binomial(logit), data = df)
plot(mod, resid(., type='response')~fitted(.), main="Normalized Residuals v Fitted Values",abline=c(0,0))
res <- resid(mod, type="response")
qqnorm(res)
qqline(res)
```

[image]
[image]

Given the large sample size I was expecting that the residuals would be normal but I was clearly wrong. I guess that these results cannot be trusted so my question is if there is any other way to analyzed this data.

Cheers and thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try to extend the random part of you GLMM with terms allowing for variance heterogeneity, spatial correlation, etc. These models and their use are well described in this book: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387874579

Comment: Also, have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html